# Flutter structure. is it good to put the modal and the provider in the same file

Tags: flutter, dart

My question is why the majority of people are using a separate file to put the model, is there is a good reason for that or just for separating the code into files.

for me, I generally use the same file for model and provider.

**what is the best practice?**

example of my code:

```
class Product with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;
  bool isFavorite;

  Product({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.description,
    @required this.price,
    @required this.imageUrl,
    this.isFavorite = false,
  });

  void _setFavValue(bool newValue) {
    isFavorite = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> toggleFavoriteStatus(String token, String userId) async {
    final oldStatus = isFavorite;
    isFavorite = !isFavorite;
    notifyListeners();
    final  url =
          "https://shopapp-aa34f-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/userFavorites/$userId/$id.json?auth=$token";

    try {
      final res = await http.put(url, body: json.encode(isFavorite));
      if (res.statusCode >= 400) {
        // error occured
        _setFavValue(oldStatus);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      _setFavValue(oldStatus);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It generally isn't a good structure to do that.  Provider is generally used as dependency injections and not for updating the ui. It would be better to learn bloc and separate all of these into three files. ui, bloc, and model

Comment: I will use bloc, but now I have figured out why. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the model and providers should be kept in different files are:

1. **Seperation of concerns**: Since models have a purpose of representing an entity in our architecture and providers act as view models holding business logic, they have different purposes and should be kept different.
2. **Independent imports**. If some other file required the use of a model, which is very common e.g. a repository class for serialization or another provider class, importing the model would also import the code of provider and vice versa.
3. **Easy collaboration**. In case of multiple team members working on a project, it could be confusing to locate the logic for a certain model. Also on github, it could be confusing to see the provider file updated while the changed were made to a model.
4. **Scaling and maintenance**. Seems to me that your cases have been very simple so far and this general practice you follow has caused no trouble for you. However, there could be use cases where a provider had to be mixed with other providers, models, shared preferences and other networking services. Debugging and maintenance of such strongly tied dependencies is going to be a nightmare.

Comment: Very well said, I would also like to add that debugging problems in production would also be harder when using provider because it is harder trace where the error came from. Event tracing is an advantage of `flutter_bloc`.